# how to handle Flask Cache Error: Can't pickle object

Tags: python, flask, caching, sqlalchemy

I want to reduce the number of requests to the most viewed articles using the following method

```
@cache.cached(timeout=60)
def most_v():
    most_viewed_limit = app.config['MOST_VIEWED_LIMIT']
    return Article.query.order_by(Article.views.desc()).limit(most_viewed_limit)
```

and then use it in the app context:

```
@app.context_processor
def my_injector():
   return dict(most_viewed_articles=most_v())
```

but when I use the **@cache.cached** decorator I get the following error:

_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.SignallingSession'>: attribute lookup SignallingSession on sqlalchemy.orm.session failed

```
          Traceback (most recent call last)
              File "mywebsite/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2091, in __call__
          return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
              File "mywebsite/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
          response = self.handle_exception(e)
              File "mywebsite/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
          response = self.full_dispatch_request()
              File "mywebsite/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
          rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
              File "mywebsite/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
          rv = self.dispatch_request()
              File "mywebsite/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
          return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
              File "mywebsite/src/main/routes.py", line 31, in home
          return render_template("main/home.html",
              File "mywebsite/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 146, in render_template
          ctx.app.update_template_context(context)
              File "mywebsite/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 756, in update_template_context
          context.update(func())
              File "app.py", line 31, in my_injector
          most_viewed_articles=most_v(),
              File "mywebsite/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_caching/__init__.py", line 479, in decorated_function
          self.cache.set(
              File "mywebsite/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_caching/backends/rediscache.py", line 157, in set
          dump = self.dump_object(value)
              File "mywebsite/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_caching/backends/rediscache.py", line 126, in dump_object
          return b"!" + pickle.dumps(value)
          _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.SignallingSession'>: attribute lookup SignallingSession on sqlalchemy.orm.session failed
```

Comment: Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message. You can anonymize paths, but you should copy and paste starting at the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):`, and format it as code.

Comment: sorry about the delay, I included the traceback

Comment: getting the same error with `@cache.memoize`. Do you find any solution ?